# Finder Sync Extension unable to read/write file from Desktop

Tags: swift, macos, appstore-sandbox, findersync

I'm trying to read a file from Desktop using Finder Sync Extension context menu, but it's not working as expected. I have added all required sandbox settings and other file locations like Downloads are working fine, but Desktop files are not.

Are there any other settings related to Desktop to read/write files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was resolved by adding explicitly the absolute path for desktop location in entitlement keys.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Desktop location included in `directoryURLs` property of the FinderSync controller?

> /*
>   For each directory present in directoryURLs, the extension can receive -beginObservingDirectoryAtURL: and -endObservingDirectoryAtURL: for that directory and for any directories inside. Always set directoryURLs when the extension starts; if there are no directories to be watched, pass the empty set.
>   */

```
open var directoryURLs: Set<URL>!
```

You should determine if the issue is due to Sandbox access violation, or an access-level misuse of the FinderSync extension API itself:

```
let rootDirectory = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/")
FIFinderSyncController.default().directoryURLs = [rootDirectory]
```

Comment: Yes, I included everything but now the problem has been resolved by adding desktop absolute path in entitlement keys explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolve by poster, but here's an example:
(this is based on an answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58389937/3276518)

Mainly:

Access that can be set directly from Xcode
`com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-only` and
`com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only`

Absolute path:
`com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-only`

Home relative path:
`com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-only`

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-only</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/<username>/Music/access.txt</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-only</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Desktop/access.txt</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The `Documents` folder is not the main folder of the user. In Sandbox context, there's a `Documents` folder in the container.